# Browse Server button in CKEditor Image Properties Dialog box not visible

Tags: ckeditor

I have downloaded and installed CKEditor and CKFinder. When I click on Image button it launches a Image Properties dialog box. However I cannot see a Browse Server button. What could be the problem. Is it something to do with permissions. I am trying to integrate CKFinder with CKEditor. Please help me.
I have given below the link for demo of CKFinder integration with CKEditor.
http://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo#ckeditor
In my asp.net application i am trying to integrate them together.
I am using demo version of CKFinder. Is it something to do with license limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [filebrowser](http://ckeditor.com/addon/filebrowser) plugin.

Read more about [how to install plugins in CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins).